# 'Cannot find "show" function' error when parameter is instance of Show

Tags: haskell, tree, show

The following error is triggered:

```
ERROR - Cannot find "show" function for:
*** Expression : debugFunction getDebugTree
*** Of type    : Tree (Tree Int) -> Bool
```

when running `debugFunction getDebugTree`

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)

getDebugTree :: Tree Int
getDebugTree = (Node 1 (Empty) (Node 2 Empty Empty))

debugFunction :: Show a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
debugFunction _ _ = True
```

I've read that

> reverse []
>
> ERROR: Cannot find "show" function for: 
>   *** expression  : reverse [] 
>   *** of type     : [a]
>
> The top-level system for Hugs can only print values which belong to a
>   type which can be shown, that is a type which belongs to the Show
>   class. Now, the list type is an instance of Show, so what is wrong
>   with reverse [] (which evaluates to [])? The problem is that the type
>   of [] is polymorphic: [] :: [a] for all a. Not knowing a Hugs refuses
>   to print a value of type [a]. Note that this behaviour applies to all
>   polymorphic values. Given the definition
>
> data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
>
> we have, on evaluating
>
> Empty
>
> the error message
>
> ERROR: Cannot find "show" function for: 
>   *** expression  : Empty 
>   *** of type     : Tree a
>
> Functions can be shown, but not very helpfully; printing any function
>   results in
>
> << function>>

As far as I understand Hugs doesn't know a so it refuses to print it (even though I'm printing a Bool?) so I've tried to make a be an instance of Show, but it still doesn't work, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the type of `debugFunction`.

```
debugFunction :: Show a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
```

`debugFunction` expects two arguments, the second of which is a `Tree a`. You're only passing it one. The type checker sees that you're passing a `Tree Int` as the first argument and infers `a ~ Tree Int`. So `debugFunction getDebugTree` is a *function* waiting for a second argument of type `Tree (Tree Int)`.

```
debugFunction getDebugTree :: Tree (Tree Int) -> Bool
```

I suspect you intended to use `getDebugTree` as the second argument to `debugFunction`, which means you need to come up with an `Int` to use as the first one.

```
debugFunction 0 getDebugTree :: Bool
```

The error message about the missing `Show` instance comes from the REPL itself. It's attempting to print out the result of `debugFunction getDebugTree`, but it can't because functions can't be shown.

Comment: @Aeron GHCi often produces better errors -- Hugs is no longer developed while GHC is. Indeed, the GHCi error contains a probable cause: "(maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)"